# How to load very big html file into IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have following task: to make very big html file (100000 short text lines) that this file can be loaded into IE during 5-10 seconds. Now I have made simple html files

```
<html>
    <body>
       lines
    </body>
</html>
```

But this file is loaded by IE during 30 seconds. How can I optimize it? Should I add any additional headers for it that IE loads it faster? Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to load in so much data?

Comment: It is task for my university work.

Comment: Can you not use something like ajax to load in the content dynamically? It will lower the load times drastically.

Comment: Just for fun I created a file with 100,000 lines as you specified and it loaded in less than a second in IE9. 300,000 lines took 2.5 seconds (but this depends on sysconfig of course). Is upgrading a possibility? Or, why would you actually have one file so large? Split it up and link to the parts (as with a page-flipper).

Answer (score 1):

Some common advices: http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/

Also, sometimes it is pretty important to set `<head>` part and `DOCTYPE` so the browser could correctly parse and render the data.

Answer (score 1):

load lines 1-20000 into one frame and 20000-50000 into another frame  and 50000-70000 into seprate frame and 70000-100000 in to another one, so we should use javascript to create a frame that contains all of the frames innerHTML.

even , we can use html file instead of frame!